# Remove "Launch blog program to post"

Tags: 2010, blog

How do I remove "Launch blog program to post" from the SharePoint 2010 blog page??? Any suggestions will be GREATLY appreciated.
Thanks!!!

Comment: I've added the 2010 tag to your post to make it easier discoverable in the future for others. Hope you don't mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you didn't specify your SharePoint version I'm assuming 2010.

Adding the following CSS code will hide the link:

```
<style type="text/css">
.ms-blogAdminLinks li+li+li+li
{
    display: none;
}
</style>
```

You can either add the above code directly to your masterpage, e.g. by using SharePoint Designer.

Or you can add a Content Editor or Simple Form WebPart to the page and paste the code into the source view of the WebPart. I prefer the Simple Form WebPart, BTW.

***UPDATE:*** Assuming you are using the default masterpage, the above CSS code will also work with SharePoint 2007 but only for Webbrowsers other than Internet Explorer (no matter which version).

If you need to get it working with SharePoint 2007 and IE you need to resort to a JavaScript based solution.

Comment: Thanks Sig Weber!!! I'll try your SharePoint 2010 suggestion.

Comment: I used the html form web part and the code above to hide the "Launch program to post" link and it works! Then I checked the box to hide the web part and put the web part under the Tools web part. Works Great! I'm using SP 2010 enterprise. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, replace the webpart with a content editor and just include the links you want

Comment: Cool and easy idea! Unfortunately undesirable in my case because it would make the links visible to everybody, including people who might not have permissions to create a new post and also anonymous users (which in my case was the reason why I developed the CSS based solution).